# Android studio: apk is not installing

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, mobile, apk

I am working on react-native application and for running app I have tried with emulator and on emulator apk is shwoing on screen and it's working fine but when I tried it with physical device I am getting log of that app installed on my phone but apk is not showing.

**Note:** Previously it's showing apk in my same device but after uninstalling and tried to installing again it's not showing.

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Device: Realme 6 Pro
Virtual decice: Pixel 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one-thing if it's working fine on other device then xender or any other application through share your apk file and install it to your realme device and then do again build your app.
May it will resolve your problem.